# Coloring geom_bars based upon values in dataset

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like my bars to be red when the value is below zero. This is not the actual data I am working with but I hope this will create a reproduce-able example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(car)

mtcars$carnames <- rownames(mtcars)
rownames(mtcars) <- 1:nrow(mtcars)

subsetCars <- as.data.frame(head(mtcars, n = 20))
subsetCars[1,4] <- -50

myplot.p <- ggplot(subsetCars, aes(x = subsetCars$carnames, y = subsetCars$hp))
myplot.p + geom_bar(stat = 'identity', 
                    fill = ifelse(subsetCars$hp > 0, "lightblue", "firebrick")) +
  coord_flip()
```

[image: link to cars barplot]

One bar is colored red, but not the one with the negative value. I have a similar problem with the current viz I am working on as well.
Advice?

Comment: It works fine for me. You don't need to use `$` subsetting in `aes` if you're specifying a `data` parameter, though; just put in the bare variable name.

Comment: Thank you for the edit! I cannot post images yet so I had to provide a link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that your `fill` argument in `geom_bar` takes a vector created by `ifelse`, of which the first element is "firebrick" and all other elements are "lightblue". So the first (bottom-most) bar will be filled with red.  However, the first bar does not correspond to the row with the negative value, since the observations have been re-ordered by `carnames` in alphabetical order.

A more idiomatic way of plotting your desired chart is

```
myplot.p <- ggplot(subsetCars, aes(x = carnames, y = hp, fill = hp < 0))
myplot.p + geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
  scale_fill_manual("Negative hp", values = c("lightblue", "firebrick")) +
  coord_flip()
```

where the `$` subsetting is unnecessary, as @alistaire pointed out, and the `fill` aesthetic can be stated in `ggplot()`.

[image]

Comment: I think I understand. So Scale_fill is actually searching for the fill declaration within aes and then changing the fill based upon that argument and the argument within values?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are having is that when you are specifying the fill, ggplot is not assigning that aesthetic in the same order that it is for the names. So to make sure the order is preserved, you need to put the greater than zero variable with the other aesthetics.

The unfortunate side effect of this is you need to manually set the colors and remove the fill scale legend.

```
ggplot(subsetCars, aes(x = subsetCars$carnames, y = subsetCars$hp,
fill = hp > 0)) +
geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
coord_flip() +
scale_fill_manual(values = c("TRUE" = "lightblue",
"FALSE" = "firebrick")) +
theme(legend.position = "none")
```

I hope that helps!